# Node cant access envorinment variable port

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

So I have set my PORT environment variable, lets say to 5555(using on windows cmd -> set PORT = 5555), yet when I use:
process.env.PORT, I only get undefined, ....

```
const express = require ('express');
const app = express();;

app.get('/',(req,res) => {
    res.send('Welcome To Learn How Here');
});

app.get('/api/courses',(req,res) => {
    res.send(["English for dujms","HTML","JavaScript"]);
})

const port = process.env.PORT;  //-> cant see whats wrong here???
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong in your code, just remove the spaces when you `set PORT=5555`

Comment: brilliant....no idea spaces so important in shell/cmd then.....cheers pal..